# undefined method `reviews' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm trying to create a reviews model for company pages. For this I have:

Models

```
user.rb
has_many :reviews

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :company 
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews
end
```

My reviews controller is:

```
  def create
    @company = Company.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    @review = @company.reviews.create(params[:review])
    @review.save
    redirect_to company_path(@company)
  end
```

and I have this code in the company show page:

```
  <% @company.reviews.each do |review| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Title:</strong>
      <%= review.title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Avantage:</strong>
      <%= review.avantage %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Inconvenient:</strong>
      <%= review.inconvenient %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

</br>

<%= form_for([@company, @company.reviews.build]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :avantage %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :avantage %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :inconvenient %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :inconvenient %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

However, when I go to a specific company page and try to create a review for this company I'm getting this error message  `undefined method reviews`for nil:NilClass

Comment: just look at what you're calling `reviews` on - it's nil.

Comment: how is it nil and it work when I create a review from console

Comment: well which line is the error on? Is it coming from the `@company.reviews` in your controller? If so, then `Company.find_by_slug` is returning nil.

Comment: yes you are right but i am using friendly_id instead of id so something like @company = Company.find(params[:company_id]) will not work i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `@company = Company.find_by_slug(params[:id])` use this code `@company = Company.friendly.find(params[:company_id])`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you may find useful:

1. If you're using Rails 4, you may encounter a further problem.  In the third line of your create method, you are using unsecure params directly in a .create call.  [Check out the Rails Guide page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) on "strong params".
2. If you implement strong parameters as mentioned above, you should probably deliberately omit the company_id field from the list of permitted params.
3. Assuming your users are allowed to write a review for any company in your system, it might be simpler for you to embed the company_id as a hidden field in your form. This would allow you to also simplify the controller method.  For example:

   ```
   # _form.html.erb
   <%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :company_id, value: @company.id %>
    ...bla bla bla
   <% end %>
   ```

   Then, in your reviews_controller...

   ```
   # reviews_controller.rb
   def create
     @review = Review.new(approved_params)
     if @review.save
       flash[:success] = 'Review created!'
     else
       flash[:error] = "Review wasn't saved"
     end
     @company = @review.company
     redirect_to @company
   end

   def approved_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:title, :avantage, :inconvenient, :company_id)
   end
   ```

   In your companies_controller, you should add this to your show method

   ```
   # companies_controller.rb
   def show
     @company = Company.find(params[:id]
     # add this line below...
     @review = Review.new
   end
   ```

I hope this helps.